# Strange behavior of Pywin32 while using word

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-3.5, pywin32

I am doing this:

```
import win32com.client as win32
infile = r"D:\path\to\file.docx"
# def word_table(infile):
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(infile)
word.Visible = False
rng = doc.Range()
for tbl in rng.Tables:
    for i in range(tbl.Rows.Count):
        page_name = tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
        hyper_link = tbl.Cell(i, 2).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Hyperlinks(1).Address
        print(page_name,  hyper_link)
```

This only prints `hyper_link` and not the `page_name` (Even if I change the order).
but if I do:

```
print(page_name)
print(hyper_link)
```

This works just fine.
I could not guess the reason for this unexpected behavior.

I posted it as an answer to this question:
[How to extract hyperlinks from MS Word table with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184298/how-to-extract-hyperlinks-from-ms-word-table-with-python/45190047#45190047)

Comment: Are you running this on Python 2.x or 3.x?  In 3.x I don't see how there could be any difference (other than the lack of a newline between the items), but in 2.x the parentheses in the single `print` statement means that you're actually printing a tuple - so you're getting the `repr()` of the items, not the `str()`.  Possibly `page_name` is an object with a blank `repr()`?

Comment: IPython 3.5 to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is due to the fact that Microsoft Word table have End of table cell character.

So `page_name = tbl.Cell(i, 1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text` will grab whatever text in the cell plus `CR` (`'\r'`) and `BEL` ('•') . Therefore it doesn't print properly.

`print(page_name.split('\r')[0] , hyper_link)` works just fine in this circumstances.